# What does Facebook use for this feature?

Tags: php, facebook, video, hyperlink

I am not sure this is correct SO to post on, but if not admin please feel free to move it to relevant SO or suggest me to move it.

I am using a contractor to help me create a website for some project. He has coded the entire custom website in PHP.

One feature that I requested was that links posted on the website should have the preview feature that we see in Facebook (FB) like in attached picture.

[image]

But he keeps saying that I can only use embedded code to create such preview feature. When I show him the FB preview he says FB is probably using technology of its own. Currently if I post the link from youtube to my test website it shows up as text like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtkUtNzaFPI&t=1909s

My question is:
What exactly is FB using? Is this easy to implement for any PHP developer or is it really time consuming implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "he says FB is probably using technology of its own"

His answer to your question is utter nonsense, and indicates only that he doesn't want to do what you're asking.  You hopefully aren't paying him very much.

---

What Facebook is doing is kind of sneaky, but structurally simple.  The order of operations is:

1. User enters text on Facebook page.
2. AJAX request is sent to Facebook server with text.
3. Facebook server parses and sees that there's a link in there.
4. Facebook server makes a server-side HTTP request to link destination to find out more.
5. Facebook server parses response for anything it can add to the input template that the user is seeing.
6. Facebook responds back to user (maybe web sockets?  maybe a response to that earlier AJAX request?)
7. Client-side code on the Facebook page updates what the user is seeing.

Steps 2-6 intuitively sound like they may take a lot of network time, but these tend to be very quick services (Facebook itself, YouTube, etc.) so that's usually not a problem.

The main concern here are Step 3 and Step 5.  That's where Facebook is using some custom logic that it likely spent considerable effort defining.  There may be libraries which help with that, likely made in response to the demand for this exact feature.  I don't have any to recommend, sorry.

The *technical* implementation is the easy part.  Determining from the user's text what data to fetch could be difficult.  Determining what data to put in the page could be difficult.  That depends on the scope of what you want to implement.

For example, it may be difficult to detect if the user has entered a variety of things you can respond to, but it may be easy (with a regular expression perhaps) to detect if the user has entered what *might be* a YouTube URL.  So if you reduce the problem space to *just* YouTube previews, then you may be onto something.  If you can successfully parse that YouTube link, you're in business.  Now you can hit a YouTube API and get information to send back to the page.

Continue with that pattern for other small problem spaces (previewing a link to an image, previewing a link for another popular site, etc.), and you can over time add that same feature.

Comment: Can this be implemented for GoDaddy server also?

Comment: @Zanam: I don't see why not.  Have you encountered an actual problem in that effort?

Comment: I am asking this question to reply to my contractor :) .. I think my contractors developer is screwing him by being lazy

Comment: @Zanam: That's probably more common than you think.  A lot of programmers don't want to admit the difference between "You can't do that" vs. "I don't know how to do that and don't want to bother figuring it out."  :)